# C++11: error when trying to return pair via async/future

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, future

Hoping that this is just a dumb mistake on my part. This is my first venture into multi-threading, so I don't know what I'm doing.

Here is the code in question (on my red black tree):

```
pair<unsigned long long, unsigned long long> ALTNode::height()  {
    pair<unsigned long long, unsigned long long> hl(0,0), hr(0,0), f;
    future<pair<unsigned long long, unsigned long long>> l, r;
    if (left)   
        l = async(std::launch::async,left->height());
    if (right)
        r = async(std::launch::async,right->height());
    if (left)
        hl = l.get();
    if (right)
        hr = r.get();
    f.first = ((hl.first < hr.first) ? hl.first : hr.first) + 1;
    f.second = ((hl.second > hr.second) ? hl.second : hr.second) + 1;
    return f;
}
```

Here is the generated error:

> Error 1   error C2664: 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair(const
>   std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from
>   'std::_Do_call_ret<_Forced,_Ret,_Funx,_Btuple,_Ftuple>::type' to
>   'const std::pairu_Ty1,_Ty2> &'    G:\Visual Studio
>   2012\VC\include\xrefwrap  431 1   ALT-Tree

Can you help me out here?

Comment: My guess would be that `left->height()` is a value, and not a callable entiry as required by `std::async`. But post an [MCVE.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Could the problem be that it's a recursive function then? Because this is the MCVE for this particular function.

Comment: Can't be an MCVE: `left` and `right` are undeclared identifiers. Let's asume they are `ALTNode*` pointers. `async` takes a callable - something that a function call operator `()` can be applied to. `left->height()` is `pair<unsigned long long, unsigned long long>` - not a callable. Most likely, you meant something like `async(std::launch::async, &ALTNode::height, left)`.